# Get value of item in object by variable name

Tags: c#

Given some objects that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public int thing_1 { get; set; }
    public int thing_2 { get; set; }
    public int thing_3 { get; set; }
    ....
    public int thing_100 { get; set; }
}
```

How would I do something like this:

```
int valueINeed = GetValue(MyObject, 2);
```

Which would call... (and this is where I need the help)...

```
private int GetValue(MyObject, int find)
{
    return MyObject.thing_[find];
}
```

I'd rather not go line by line in a Switch, if that can be avoided.

Comment: good point. I'll clean it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
var obj = new MyChildObject();
foreach(var prop in obj .GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    if (prop.Name == "thing_" + find.ToString())
         return prop.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```